# Swisscom Passeport two-step login with Cloud Foundry CLI

Tags: single-sign-on, cloud-foundry, paas, swisscomdev

How can I login with the Cloud Foundry CLI to the Swisscom Application Cloud when I have activated the two-step login method (password and SMS code) in my [Swisscom Passeport account](https://my.passeport.swisscom.ch/mypasseport/)?

```
$ cf login -a https://….appcloud.swisscom.com -u …
API endpoint: https://….appcloud.swisscom.com

Password> 
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
```

After entering my Passeport password on the command line I do receive the SMS code, however there's no possibility to enter it on the command line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you enable Passeport's two-factor authentication, you have to use the `--sso` flag and follow the instructions:

```
cf login -a https://api.lyra-836.appcloud.swisscom.com --sso
API endpoint: https://api.lyra-836.appcloud.swisscom.com

One Time Code ( Get one at https://login.lyra-836.appcloud.swisscom.com/passcode )>
```

Switching to the browser and obtaining an OTP is needed because the `cf` cli does not support two-step auth directly on the cli yet.

We will add this info to the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Because lots of users have problems to login to iAPC (internal Application Cloud) I post here the steps. **For external users this API endpoint is not reachable, you need to be in Corproot network (with proxy configured).**

```
unset https_proxy http_proxy HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY
cf login -a https://api.scapp-console.swisscom.com --sso
API endpoint: https://api.scapp-console.swisscom.com

One Time Code ( Get one at https://login.scapp-console.swisscom.com/passcode )> 
Authenticating...
OK

Select an org (or press enter to skip):
(...)

Select a space (or press enter to skip):
(...)

Space> test
Targeted space Test



API endpoint:   https://api.scapp-console.swisscom.com (API version: 2.92.0)
User:           xxx.xxx@swisscom.com
Org:            xxx
Space:          xxx
```

A screenshot how the One Time Code looks like (you need to copy and paste into CF CLI)

[image]

This CF installation is connected to Corproot domain. You need to use your Corproot credentials (the same you use for your Desktop).

This how to error (`Credentials were rejected, please try again`) looks if you are doing it wrong:

```
cf push
FAILED
Not logged in. Use 'cf login' to log in.

cf login
API endpoint: https://api.scapp-console.swisscom.com
Email> xxx.xxx@swisscom.com
Password>
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again
```

Comment: What if I am not in corproot? I develop on a laptop which is not on corproot. I barely use my corproot laptop.